# Le versus lui in a specific example

Tags: pronoms-personnels

I saw the following phrase in a duolingo "story"

> Vous pouvez le prendre en photo pour moi ?

I was quite sure that this should be '*lui*', as an indirect object, rather than *le*.

Am I wrong? Are *le/lui* not as analogous to Portuguese (*ele/para ele*) as I thought?

Comment: Le is the **direct** object or *prendre en photo* (and not indirect).

Comment: You need to look up "prendre quelqu'un en photo". There is no indirect object. And I would not confuse this by asking about Portuguese. The direct object in Portuguese is a, o, as, os and lhe. Also, Iberian Port. and Braz. Pt. are quite different as regards objects.

Comment: *Pode fotografá-lo para mim?*

Answer (score 2):

The correct expression is indeed

> Vous pouvez le prendre en photo pour moi ?

To mean: *Can you take a picture of him for me?*.

As @None says, the French *le* corresponds to the English *him* here. The sentence *Vous pouvez **lui** prendre en photo pour moi* is not correct and not heard or read, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Duolingo is correct here.

> Vous pouvez le prendre en photo pour moi ? (Can you take a picture of him for me?)

Let's compare this to a similar sentence with "lui":

> Vous pouvez lui dire de s'avancer? (Can you tell him to move forward?)

Let's say we are talking about a guy named Adrien.
The first sentence is equivalent to:

> Vous pouvez prendre Adrien en photo pour moi?

While the second is:

> Vous pouvez dire à Adrien de s'avancer?

You can notice how in French an indirect object implies a preposition of some kind (here it's "à"). In the first sentence Adrien is indeed a direct object since he is the thing that is taken into picture.